# Run stored procedure stored on one server on another

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2017

We try to run all our reports off stored procedures, however, now I am trying to report off a 3rd party server that I cannot deploy too. I am trying to find away to store the stored procedure on Server1, but execute on Server2 but the only link is the RDL which can see both data sets. I do not think this is possible.

Comment: Is `Server1` the `3rd party server`? Can your stored proc run from `Server2` and query `Server1`? And if the Report RDL can see both data sets, then I'm confused on what you are trying to do.

Comment: Server1 is the company DB it has the SP, Server2 is 3rd party, I can query it and get the report to work from a script. In the simplest it would say get SP on Server1, execute it on Server2 ...but there is no linked server.